# wp-admin AJAX with Fetch API is done without user

Tags: ajax, wp-admin, javascript, authentication, nonce

**TL;DR** - Why is my user account not logged in during an AJAX request which is made inside wp-admin?

---

I have the following setup:

```
<?php

add_action('wp_ajax_foobar_action', 'foobar_action');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_foobar_action', 'foobar_action');

function foobar_action() {
    check_ajax_referrer();

    wp_send_json((object) ['msg' => 'hello world']);
}

add_action('admin_print_scripts', function () {
    printf('<script type="text/javascript">window.custom_nonce = "%s";</script>', wp_create_nonce());
});
```

And in JS:

```
var msg = '';

// I'm using the whatwg-fetch polyfill and a polyfill for Promises.
fetch(ajaxurl, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'
    },
    body: 'action=foobar_action&_wpnonce=' + window.custom_nonce
}).then(function (res) {
    msg = res.json().msg;
});
```

This is all run in wp-admin. The issue is that the wp-admin page/JS script itself is loaded as a logged in user, but the AJAX request that ends up into admin-ajax.php is done as a logged out guest user. This leads to the issue of wp-admin using `nopriv` and `check_ajax_referrer` failing 100% of the time.

Why does wp-admin make AJAX requests as a guest instead of the logged in user?

Currently, the AJAX endpoint returns `403` status with `-1` content, as it should in case there is a nonce mismatch. If I comment out the `check_ajax_referrer()` call then the AJAX request runs through successfully. After some furious `console.log`ging I've determined that the nonce values match in the JS fetch call and the AJAX endpoint that receives it (which means the nonce is properly transferred, but a wrong guest nonce is generated during the AJAX endpoint execution.

If I remove the `wp_ajax_nopriv_foobar_action` then WordPress doesn't find the auth-enabled AJAX action because there seemingly is no logged in user available (results in status `200` and body `0`).

Steps I've attempted to fix the issue:

- Logged out and in again, cleared caches/cookies, used incognito windows,
- Restarted PHP-FPM, Nginx, object cache backends, MariaDB,
- Disabled all plugins that are not required for operation,
- Moved the AJAX hooking code around in my plugin code, all the way to the plugin root file (e.g. `myplugin/myplugin.php`),
- Used GET instead of POST.

Answer (score 5):

After some fiddling and sparring with @t-todua I found the issue:

With the Fetch API `fetch` call you must manually set to send cookies with a request. After setting the `credentials` option properly the cookies were sent and the AJAX endpoint recognized the current user. So the JS becomes:

```
var msg = '';

// I'm using the whatwg-fetch polyfill and a polyfill for Promises.
fetch(ajaxurl, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'
    },
    body: 'action=foobar_action&_wpnonce=' + window.custom_nonce,
    credentials: 'same-origin'
}).then(function (res) {
    msg = res.json().msg;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think problem could be due to the consequence:

in HTML source, firstly, this should be outputed:  `.......... window.custom_nonce = "%s" ...` and then should be called `fetch` function.  In `foobar_action()`, add this line: `var_dump(is_user_logged_in());` and see, maybe it detects login (if so, then reason is in nonce. Otherwise, problem is in `login`)

p.s. Have you tried changing POST to GET method?

Comment: I'll try changing to a GET request if that changes anything. The generated nonce is supplied using `wp_localize_script` but I left that out for a leaner example code.

Comment: Changing to GET changes nothing.

Comment: note, you should use AJAX request in this manner:  https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Ajax_on_the_Administration_Side
 you'b better show the source of `FETCH` function in your post. Or do a pure AJAX request like in that example.

Comment: `fetch` is a Fetch API call (which I have additionally polyfilled using `whatwg-fetch`): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: Haha, you pointed me to the right direction! The `fetch` call must manually be set to send over cookies. Enabled that and the thing seems to work. I need to do some more testing on it. Many thanks!

Comment: @ojrask ok, good if solved. (  if you did pure(correct) AJAX call, it could be solved too.)

Comment: Fetch API is as pure as can be, it is implemented by browsers (http://caniuse.com/#search=fetch) instead of having to rely on jQuery or other libraries. ;)